# Where is the span coming from in this directive example?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-templates

[This plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/41wWylKFANFA9IkPsvGG) is taken from the Angular developer guide, but it doesn't make sense to me. It's just supposed to be showing the basic functionality of transclude, which I understand, but in the rendered output you'll see there's suddenly a `span` tag. Where did that come from? It's not part of the template.

Comment: You need to fix your plunker link.

Comment: There's nothing in the refered plunk.

Comment: One minute, you're right...

Comment: Fixed, hadn't saved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your transclusion is just a text (in fact an implicit `span`), it needs to be added while compiling the HTML.

To avoid that, you can manually wrap your text around any tag, for instance a `<div>`, so that it will be inserted as is.

If you *really* want to not have any tag in between, you could write your own `compile` method in your directive, and set the text to the `element` directly, using `elem.text(content)` instead of `elem.html(content)`